# Port Number only working when using IP to connect, not URL

Tags: nginx, ip, port, url

so I have a nginx server listening on port 80.
Works fine. I can connect to it via "exampleip" and "exampleurl"

Now on my dedicated server I have another program on Port 9999
If I use "exampleip":9999 to connect it works fine
But "exampleurl":9999 doesnt work.

How to achieve this?

Comment: "I have another program on Port 9999", then that program decides what kind of incoming HTTP requests it will serve. So when "exampleurl":9999 doesnt work your hope is to check the program documentation or contact its vendor.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that cloudflare does not support port 9999. Using a different one now and it works 